# Is there a way to get Django's default string for date and time from Python's datetime?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've noticed that the default Django's datetime as a string looks like this (from the template):

```
April 4, 2012, 6 a.m.
April 14, 2012, 12:06 p.m.
April 14, 2012, midnight
April 14, 2012, noon
April 14, 2012, 6:02 a.m.
```

Notice how there are no trailing zeros in the date or the time. Also Django eliminates :00 minutes and also uses the string "noon" and "midnight" instead of the equivalent numerical times.

The closest I could get without coding a bunch of `if`-`elif` statements is this

```
# I'm using Django 1.4 with timezone support.
# timezone.now() is the same as `datetime.now()` but it's timezone "aware".
timezone.now().strftime('%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p').replace( 'AM', 'a.m.' ).replace( 'PM', 'p.m.' )
```

But that would produce the following (using the same example above)

```
April 04, 2012, 06:00 a.m.
April 14, 2012, 12:06 p.m.
April 14, 2012, 12:00 a.m.
April 14, 2012, 12:00 p.m.
April 14, 2012, 06:02 a.m.
```

The reason I need to get a string is because I'm using ajax (specifically Dajax) so I *have* to return a string of `datetime` since I can't store a Python object in JSON (even if I could, JavaScript won't know how to interpret it).

So is there some sort of Django function that can convert `datetime` into the same string that Django's template uses?

Comment: Perhaps django accomplishes that formatting with the help of its own module: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/dateformat.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `django.utils.dateformat` which Steven linked to:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.utils import dateformat
>>> dateformat.format(datetime.datetime.now(), 'F j, Y, P')
u'April 14, 2012, 1:31 p.m.'
```

`P` is the interesting extension to `strftime`, on [line 93](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/dateformat.py#L93):

```
Time, in 12-hour hours, minutes and 'a.m.'/'p.m.', with minutes left off
if they're zero and the strings 'midnight' and 'noon' if appropriate.
Examples: '1 a.m.', '1:30 p.m.', 'midnight', 'noon', '12:30 p.m.'
Proprietary extension.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one lazy way to do it:

```
def f(dt):
    s = dt.strftime('%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
    for unwanted, wanted in [
        ('12:00 AM', 'midnight'),
        ('12:00 PM', 'noon'),
        ('AM','a.m.'),
        ('PM', 'p.m.'),
        (':00', ''),
        (' 0', ' ')]:
        s = s.replace(unwanted, wanted)
    return s
```

This

```
print f(datetime(2012, 4, 4, 6))
print f(datetime(2012, 4, 14, 12, 6))
print f(datetime(2012, 4, 14, 12))
print f(datetime(2012, 4, 14, 0))
print f(datetime(2012, 4, 14, 6, 2))
```

gives

```
April 4, 2012, 6 a.m.
April 14, 2012, 12:06 p.m.
April 14, 2012, noon
April 14, 2012, midnight
April 14, 2012, 6:02 a.m.
```

Comment: You link to the real way to do it then don't use it? :)

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski Thanks, although I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I did learn some cool list/tuple strategy in replacing "unwanted" text. :-)